# VBA code to compare two columns from two worksheets and copy the common data

Tags: excel, vba

I have 1 million records in one sheet(sheet 1) and 16k records in another sheet(sheet 2).Based on the first 20 characters from the each line from sheet 2 it should check the each line in the sheet 1 and copy that row in a separate column in any of the sheet.I have recorded the sample macro for first record but i would like to mention as cells range for all the functionalities here instead of data to address it on entire column.

```
Sub test1()
'
' test1 Macro
' test1
'

'
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "XYZ00026245931CA9B05500045Y80Invalid value in code ID"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("D1").Select
    Cells.Find(What:="XYZ00026245931CA9B05", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:= _
        xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:= _
        xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    Range("C1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "XYZ00026245931CA9B05005000000000000004500Y8                     "
    Range("D1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just use a `vlookup()` to do this?

Comment: Here i don't want to compare the complete row data from the sheet 2 .Just first 20 characters from it.Also am new to VBA code.Also the sheet 1 has 1 million records.Can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Create a new column in your data which has only the first 20 characters `=LEFT(A1,20)`. Then you can VLOOKUP the value you want with ease.

Comment: But the row in the sheet 1 which has 1 million records has 40 characters which i need those all 40 characters desperately in a separate column.it's an urgent issue.Can you help me on this? sample record from sheet - XYZ00026245931CA9B05005000000000000004500Y8  sample record from sheet 2 -XYZ00026245931CA9B05500045Y80Invalid value in code ID

Comment: You can brute force run a for loop to do this. But for each of 16k record on sheet 2, it will search the Sheet1 1 million times. Are you okay with that ?
It will run 16k * 1 Million times which is ideally not recommended

Comment: oh ok..What is the ideal way to do it? Since it's a production issue for which we need that 16k records from that sheet 1.Can you help me to fix this?

Comment: With the above VBA code for 1 record,can we able to alter it in such a way to address it for the bulk records?

Comment: Is their any way to trim these characters alone from that data "invalid value in code ID" Since in the left side the size differs from one to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are familiar with the vlookup function, if so then you can use a partial vlookup to accomplish your task.

Assuming the following:

1. Lookup value: Sheet 2, column A
2. Lookup Table: Sheet 1, columns A to B
3. Return value: Column 2 of the lookup table

**Adjust this formula to your needs:**(currently set up to be used on sheet 2, first row)

=VLOOKUP(LEFT($A1,20)&"*",Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE)

Comment: It's returning N/A for all values. Here i can able to trim the unwanted characters by using LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-26) in the sheet 2.Now i need to compare the remaining data with sheet 1 records and need to return the matching records from the sheet1

Comment: For this method, I think you would want a helper column in Sheet2 with `=LEFT(A1,20)`, then a helper column in Sheet1 with the same. You could compare get the results in Sheet3 using `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$1000000,MATCH(Sheet2!B1,Sheet1!$B$1:$B$1000000,0))`. This assumes that the helper columns are Column B in both Sheet1 and Sheet2.

Comment: Both VLOOKUP and index options worked out.Thanks for timely help.

Answer (score 0):

This was a useful learning tool for me, so I went ahead and created VBA that answers your original question. As Jitendra Singh mentioned, this is brute force and resource, consumptive. On my machine, it took ~20 seconds to do just 1000 rows. so, for your 16,000 entries it could easily take over 5 minutes. With this in mind, I designed it with a couple of safety nets:

- user input to determine how many rows you're going to review at once. I'd recommend taking it in small bites.
- a timer that will pause every 10 seconds to make sure you want to keep going (adjust the time at the `If tmElapsed > 10 Then` line)
- a warning in case the user selects more than 1000 rows (adjust the number of rows for the warning at the `If rngCompare.Cells.Count > 1000 Then` line)

That said, here's what I came up with:

```
Sub Compare20char()
' This Sub will look in the cells specified by the user.
' It will compare the first 20 characters of those cells to the first 20 characters in
' the cells in Sheet1, beginning at A2 and continuing to the end of the data in Column A.
' For each match, it will copy the entire cell in Sheet1, Column A to an array.
' After completing its review, it will paste that array to the first empty cell in Column A of Sheet3.

    Dim cell, rngSource, rngCompare, rngTarget As Range
    Dim arrData() As Variant
    Dim i, LastRow As Integer
    Dim tmRef, tmElapsed, tmTotal As Double

    Set rngSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A" & WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A")))
    i = 0

'Get A Cell Address From The User to Get Number Format From
  On Error Resume Next
    Set rngCompare = Application.InputBox( _
      Title:="Select Reference Range", _
      Prompt:="Select the cells in Sheet2 for which you would like to retrieve the data in Sheet 1.", _
      Type:=8)
  On Error GoTo 0

'Test to ensure User Did not cancel and rngCompare is not excessively large
    If rngCompare Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If rngCompare.Cells.Count > 1000 Then
        If MsgBox("You have selected " & rngCompare.Cells.Count & " cells. This may take extended time to run. Continue?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "Warning") = vbNo Then GoTo EscapeHatch
    End If

' Begin timer
    tmRef = Timer

' Begin loop to review each cell and fill array
    For Each cell In rngCompare
        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngSource, Left(cell, 20) & "*") = 1 Then
            i = i + 1
            ReDim Preserve arrData(1 To i)
            arrData(i) = cell.Value
            tmElapsed = Timer - tmRef
            If tmElapsed > 10 Then
                If MsgBox("Since the last break:" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Run time: " & Round(tmElapsed, 2) & " seconds" & vbNewLine _
                    & "Records reviewed: " & i & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Continue?" & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
                    "(If you select ""No"", the spreadsheet will be unchanged.)", vbQuestion + vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, _
                    "Extended Run Time") = vbNo Then GoTo EscapeHatch
                tmTotal = tmTotal + tmElapsed
                tmRef = Timer
            End If
        End If
    Next

' Paste array to end of Column A in Sheet3
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End With
    Set rngTarget = Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A" & LastRow & ":A" & LastRow + i - 1)
    rngTarget = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(arrData)

' Report results
    tmTotal = tmTotal + tmElapsed
    Debug.Print tmTotal
    MsgBox "Run time: " & Round(tmTotal, 2) & " seconds" & vbNewLine & "Records reviewed: " & i & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Records pasted to Sheet3."

Exit Sub

EscapeHatch:
    tmTotal = tmTotal + tmElapsed
    MsgBox "Run time: " & Round(tmTotal, 2) & " seconds" & vbNewLine & "Records reviewed: " & i & _
        vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "No changes made."

End Sub
```

Good luck.